# Update textbox value when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my problem, when i click the submit button, the textbox doesn't show any value 
Is there any mistakes, i am just a newbie
Thank you very much

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" >

      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="setValue" id="setValue" value="submit" onclick="setValue()"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>
          <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
       </p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue()
    {
        document.getElementById('bbb').value="new value here";
    }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue is that **you're using the same name for the element as the function**, so `window.setValue` is not the function, but the submit button, and that's an error.

The second issue is that when you hit the ***submit*** button, the form is submitted and the page reloads, that's why you wont see a value, you have to prevent the form from submitting.

You could do it with javascript, but the easiest would be to just use a regular button instead of the submit button.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="set_Value" id="set_Value" value="submit" onclick="setValue()" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="bbb" id="bbb" />
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setValue() {
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = "new value here";
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hMLt9/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i have fixed it after delete "<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">" and "</form>" ,also correct the element name and the function name

Comment: @user3635102 - Okay, remember to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

I was typing the same answer what Adeneo just given, thank you Adeneo.
And user3635102, your `<form>` was good, you can keep it as it was. Only you need to change `<input type="submit">` to `<input type="button">` . if you need to submit the form in future you can update your Javascript as follows which will submit form1:

```
<script>
    function setValue() {
        document.getElementById('bbb').value = "new value here";
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
</script>
```