# how do i get the button value to display in the text box

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code, how do i get the button value to display in the text box.
I tried this but it didn't work

```
<p>Click the button to return the value of its value attribute.</p>

<button id="myBtn" value="myvalue" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<input id="demo" readonly>


<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>
```

this is a link from fiddle where i tried it https://jsfiddle.net/mp5pndyw/

Comment: You should use `value` instead of `innerHTML` if you want to display the value on a textbox.

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").value = x`, your `input` element shows the value not the HTML. Also that fiddles' code is completely different from the question.

Comment: Well for a start you haven't assigned a `type` to your input and inputs have `value`s and do not contain `innerHTML`... Also your jsfiddle is very different to the source code in your question.

Comment: Here is an answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23798989/update-textbox-value-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: I don't believe the `button` element can have a `value`

Comment: @clabe45 a `button` element can have a value.

Comment: Oh I just saw that the OP explicitly set it

Answer (score 1):

Here's your fiddle modified to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/mp5pndyw/1/

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')
var textbox = document.getElementById('display')

for (let i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
 buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  textbox.value = e.target.value
 })
}
```

```html
<form method = "POST" action = "addprocess.php">
 <fieldset>
 <legend align="center">Semester Courses</legend><br><br>
 <div class="row"><label style="font-family: verdana; font-size: 25px;">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;BIOLOGY&emsp;</label>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="display" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" readonly>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" id="dropdown0" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Click to Select
        </button>
    
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8803">BIOL 8803</button>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8805">BIOL 8805</button>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" value="BIOL 8807">BIOL 8807</button>
          <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" option value="BIOL 8809">BIOL 8809</button>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br><br>
<input name="submit" type ="submit" value="click to submit">
<input name="reset" type ="reset" value="Reset">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you not think it would be a good idea to point out the changes you have made and explain the reason for those changes so that people can understand why the current source code isn't functioning as intended?

Comment: @Christopher Messer please can you try running my code on your browser, i noticed that my legend only shows on fiddle but does not show on browser. Do you have any ideas as to why it is so?

Comment: hey @ebi - what legend are you referring to? can you provide an updated fiddle and show me the issue?

Comment: thanks @Christopher i have figured it out, i have another challenge though, i need to know how to auto resize the text to fit the textbox in case of longer text

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `innerHTML` of the text input. Instead, you need to use `value`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").value = x;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to return the value of its value attribute.</p>

<button id="myBtn" value="myvalue" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<input id="demo" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely why your example is not working, when attempting it I kept getting a console error that it violates a policy. If however you just want it to work, you could always remove your onclick attribute and use the following javascript:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var myInput = document.getElementById("demo")
  myInput.value = e.srcElement.value
} 

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction)
```

This adds the listener via javascript (ie addEventListener... ). You can then access the element you clicked via the event (e), also making the function reusable for similar situations. Happy coding!